# Select values from table with multiple attributes

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:
1: products (id, name)
2: product_attributes (attribute_id, name)
3: product_attributes_selected (product_id, attribute_id,value)

Now I want to get all product_id that have two or more desired attributes and values
How can I accomplish that?

I tried this, but it failed:

```
select p.id,p.nazwa_pl 
from produkty p,produkty_atrybuty_wartosci paw 
where (paw.atrybut_id=2 and paw.wartosc=4) 
  and (paw.atrybut_id=3 and paw.wartosc=0) 
  and p.id=paw.produkt_id 
group by p.id
```

Comment: If it failed, please share the error you encountered, if any.  If it failed because you didn't get the expected result, then you need to share the data you are feeding into the query and the expected result.  Please be as descriptive/transparent as you can be regarding the issue, it will help the community help you faster and with more detail.

Comment: it returs empty query, but when I check it in phpmyadmin, atleast 3 products match this selection

Comment: As T McKeown suggested in his answer below, perhaps you have an issue with the grouping of your `and` statements in your query.  If his answer works for you, great; otherwise, you will need to share your data and expected results for others to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'n my example we have a table named Attribs, some how you need to create (e.g. TABLE variable, or CTE or some other way), my code will show you how to JOIN it.

```
CREATE TABLE Attribs( Attrib INT,  Val INT )
```

^^ Populate some data in it...  (again could be automated) ^^

```
select p.id,p.nazwa_pl 
from produkty p
JOIN produkty_atrybuty_wartosci paw 
  ON  p.id=paw.produkt_id 
JOIN Attribs AS A
  ON A.Attrib = paw.atrybut_id
 AND A.Val = paw.wartosc
```

Comment: You used OR, so it shows p.id with one of the two attributs, but I must select only thouse products that have exacly desired attributs

Here is XML with attributs data: http://kielkowski-szkolka.pl/attributs_data.xml

Comment: I row have only 1 atrybut, but there can be multiple attributs for 1 product. I just want to filter products for certain attributs, like in other shops :)

Comment: I "think" you are asking how to have your xml data as the where criteria for a select?  Your question is not clear as to what EXACTLY you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok sorry for chaos. I will try to describe this one more time.

Comment: Ok sorry for chaos. I will try to describe this better. table produkty_atrybuty_wartosci contains product_id with attribute_id and its value. One product can have multiple attributs, but one attribute contains only 1 value (for 1 product). Now I wan to filter products using one or more combo atribute+value. For example I want to show only produts that "color" (attributer) is "red" (value), and  "size" (attribute) is "XXL" (value)

Comment: I see...  so yes you would need to generate a second table and join to it...  I will expand my answer assuming you create and populate the second table

Answer (score 1):

With the following query you get all ids. The idea is the following: you get all products that have the attribute 2 OR 3 OR 4. Afterwards, you group the result by the product id and count the grouped items (`grouped`). Only those entries that group 3 entries (you are searching for 3 attribute ids) are sufficient. Obviously, the resulting products can have more attributes, but you asked for *at least* the provided attributes.

```
SELECT p.id, p.nazwa_pl, paw.bibkey, paw.keywordid, COUNT(*) as grouped
FROM produkty p, produkty_atrybuty_wartosci paw
WHERE p.id=paw.produkt_id AND paw.atrybut_id IN (2, 3, 4) GROUP BY p.id
HAVING grouped = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a table1 `resource` with columns `{'id','name',....}` and a table2 `resource_attribute` with columns `{'id','resource_id','attribute_name','attribute_value'}` where column `resource_id` is a foreign key pointing to `Resource.id`, you can do it in this way:

```
SELECT r.* FROM resource r LEFT JOIN resource_attribute ra ON r.id = ra.resource_id
AND (
    (ra.NAME = 'height' AND ra.VALUE = '20') #First attribute
    OR
    (ra.NAME = 'color' AND ra.VALUE = 'blue') #Second attribute
)
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 #Total number of attributes searched
```

of course if you want to make it dynamic, and use the attributes name and values you need, you can save the number of attributes you want to use in your query and reuse it in the final `COUNT(*)` function.

I use this query dynamic in my code (java) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy I found ansfer that works for me

```
SELECT p.id,p.nazwa_pl FROM produkty p JOIN produkty_atrybuty_wartosci paw ON p.id=paw.produkt_id  WHERE (paw.atrybut_id,paw.wartosc) IN ((2,4),(3,0)) GROUP BY p.id, p.nazwa_pl HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT paw.atrybut_id)=2
```

Thanks for Your help and time